# Made my first server and I need help with the scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I know how scoreboards work, and i have one set up already. the thing is, its set to `totalKillCount` and give 1 point for each kill. I want to give more points for killing tougher mobs.

How do I make it so it gives different points for different mobs, but also have all of the scores show up on the same scoreboard? For example, 2 points for killing a creeper, but 7 points for killing a ravager?

My server is a PvP and PvE.

Comment: The scoreboard does not have enough flexibility to give different point values for different mobs killed. I’m going to look into using advancements to detect different mobs killed.

Comment: Aww, I was hoping it would work. The advancements thing sounds like a really good idea, though. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 have you found anything yet? no rush, just curious

Comment: I know that it'll definitely work, but I just need to think about the implementation for a second. Sorry for not getting back to you for this long, I'm a busy user—online and offline!

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 oh, it's fine, don't worry about not getting back to me. I'm probably not as busy as you online, but I do have quite a few offline things I need to do each day. Also, it feels so weird that only a month ago, I was a new user with 1 reputation, but now I technically have 400 (i removed 100 for a bounty) rep. Thanks for helping me get started!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can test for when a player kills an entity and add a point to a `dummy` score that will be displayed:

```
execute as @a if score @s Cre matches 1 run scoreboard players add <player> TK 1
```

`Cre` has the score `minecraft.killed:minecraft.creeper` and will detect when a player kills a creeper. `TK` is the displayed score. The command adds 1 to the `TK` score and this will show how many creepers the players have killed, or how many points a player has.

In the `<player>` area you can add a custom name so that it will say something like, `CreepersKilled`, but you won't be able to see which player it belongs to.

By adding a real player in the `<player>` area you can test for specific players using their names, but this requires that you set up commands for every player separately.

And there is no way to display scores to only one player unless you use a plugin (and maybe a datapack).

As I said above it can be done if you know all players that will play and set up dedicated commands for each and every one. Otherwise, I would recommend using a plugin, can't give any suggestions on plugins sorry.

Comment: oh wow, ive never used /execute commands before i had no idea they could do so many things!! i'll try it and get back to you